# Starting wso2 3.0.0 gateway windows "Could not load Logmanager"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, ballerina

So i am trying to load the WSO2 gateway from my local machine running the new 3.0.0-m6 version downloaded from their website.

I have run everything as described in the quickstart guide, and i get the following error on start up.

```
Could not load Logmanager "org.ballerinalang.launcher.BLogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ballerinalang.launcher.BLogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:195)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:181)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(ClassLogger.java:55)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(ConnectorBootstrap.java:846)
    at sun.management.Agent.startLocalManagementAgent(Agent.java:138)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:260)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
ballerina: unknown command 'start'
Run 'ballerina help' for usage.
```

- ActiveMQ is running
- WSO2 Server is running
- WSO2 Identity manager is running
- WSO2 API Manager is running
- I am starting the gateway from the root folder as explained in the start up guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this in Windows? The version 3.0.0-m6 is based on Ballerina v0.89 and in this version of Ballerina, there's a bug in the `bin/ballerina.bat`file. As you can see, it's looking for a class named `org.ballerinalang.launcher.BLogManager` and fails. This class was moved to another package and now, its fully qualified name is `org.ballerinalang.logging.BLogManager`. In the `ballerina.bat` script, change the property (towards the end of the file) `-Djava.util.logging.manager="org.ballerinalang.launcher.BLogManager"` to `-Djava.util.logging.manager="org.ballerinalang.logging.BLogManager"` and it should solve your problem.